# How to interrupt an onclick call and put in my own?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I'm making a site that uses JavaScript, jQuery, and jPlayer to make an audio playlist. I am still slowly teaching myself JavaScript, so I am a bit confused.

I have a link element on the jPlayer that I want to let the user click and have it load the corresponding post on my music blog. My jPlayer and jQuery code that I included are both written in shorthand so I can't decipher what is actually going on.

The element that I want to change is written as `a.jp-playlist-item`. Is there an easy way in JavaScript to add an onclick function that will override the default one that jPlayer has set up so I can open a new tab and redirect them to a site?

If you want to look at my site, it's http://www.startingtofeelit.com and the link I'm trying to make is on the top music player.

Comment: You can unbind any click events bound directly to the element using `.off`

Comment: You can "de-minify" the jPlayer code by using a javascript prettifier website, if you want to better understand what is going on in the code.  On a personal note, please make sure you have a good reason for the extra tab; this kind of browser behavior is just irritating to most users, if the behavior is not what the user expected to happen when they clicked.

Answer (score -1):

You should use preventDefault

```
$(".yourClass").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // DO SOME STUFF
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the jplayer action is not the default one. What might help, though, would be to `stopImmediatePropagation`

Comment: So I tried to do what you said. Maybe I'm not including the correct class or something. Upon inspecting the element in Firefox, I saw 'a.jp-playlist-item.jp-playlist-current'. I tried using '$(".jp-playlist-item")', '$(".jp-playlist-current")', and '$(".jp-playlist-item.jp-playlist-current")' from your code above, but to no avail. Am I doing something wrong?

I just used this code below to check if it was working. It is in my header.

$(".jp-playlist-current").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert("Hi");
  });

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry for the misunderstanding...
The JQuery selector, was not correct in my last answer.

Just do this:

```
$(".jp-seek-bar").replaceWith($(".jp-seek-bar").clone())
$(".jp-seek-bar").click(function(){ 
    alert(1);
    /*WRITE YOU CODE HERE*/
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Didn't seem to do anything. I tried with and without a ; after your first line.

Comment: Ensure that the code is executed afted the jPlayer initiation. To be sure, add a script at the end of you page, that does: $(document).ready(function() { /*PREVIOUS CODE*/ })

Comment: You can test the code above on the chrome console, for example. If you put the code above on the chrome console, you will see that it works... I think that you are not initiating that code in the right place.

Comment: A few things... Why would I use `jp-seek-bar`? I don't want it to be when they click the seek bar, but when they click the name of the song. When I inspect the element in Firefox, it says `a.jp-playlist-item.jp-playlist-current`. Tried changing it to that, but no luck. I put this in my document.ready function.

Comment: In that case you need this code: $("a.jp-playlist-item").each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).clone()) }) $("a.jp-playlist-item").click(function(){alert(1);}) sorry for the misunderstanding. Test on google chrome/firefox console first

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing any parenthesis or semicolons or anything? I tried copying and pasting your code and it just made it so the jPlayer doesn't work at all.

Comment: Have you tried to put that code on google chrome console or firefox console? I have tried there and it worked fine

Comment: I copied and pasted it into Chrome console and get `SyntaxError: unexpected identifier`

Comment: You are missing the semicolons... Put the semicolons on the code and try it on google chrome console again: $("a.jp-playlist-item").each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).clone()) }); $("a.jp-playlist-item").click(function(){alert(1);});